# FileNotFoundError con archivos en mismo directorio

Tags: python, vscode

Estoy teniendo éste error:

> (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'piezas.txt')

Al llamar un archivo **`.txt`** que se encuentra en el mismo directorio.

El código es bastante sencillo:

```
PIEZAS = open('piezas.txt')
```

Ya he intentado pasarle la ruta completa e igual me salta el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Lo pruebas dentro del IDE? Mira que directorio de trabajo (working directory) tienes configurado para ese código.

Comment: Solucionado! Lo que hice fue agregar la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto al workspace (antes tenía abierta la carpeta donde tengo guardados todos mis proyectos). Gracias por la idea! @CandidMoe

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Mi python está roto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594322/mi-python-est%c3%a1-roto)