# FileNotFoundError en Python con archivos en mismo directorio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy queriendo acceder al contenido de un archivo de texto, pero me sale un error que no puedo solucionar.

Acá tengo el código:

```
archivo = open("archivo_texto.txt")
print(archivo)
```

Y acá está la carpeta:

```
lectura_archivos
├── archivo_texto.txt
└── lectura_archivo_texto.py
```

Ya probé usar rutas relativas, rutas absolutas, cambiar el nombre de los archivos, y aún así no me funciona. ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué puede ser?

PD: Me sale el siguiente error:

> *FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'archivo_texto.txt'*

Pero no tiene sentido, porque claramente el `archivo.txt` está en la misma carpeta.

Comment: Para ayudarte es necesario que expliques cómo estás ejecutando tu código.

Comment: Sugiero editar el título de la pregunta, agrega `FileNotFoundError`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes `open("archivo_texto.txt")` el sistema operativo busca el archivo en el *directorio actual*.
Todo lo que necesitas saber al respecto lo puedes encontrar en esta pregunta:
[¿Qué es el directorio de trabajo actual, cómo lo determino y cómo lo cambio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593072)

Si escribes la ruta completa, la ruta absoluta de tu archivo, no deberías tener ese problema.
Si no quieres escribirla a mano, puedes ayudarte con la librería [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/pathlib.html).
Podemos tomar el directorio del archivo `lectura_archivo_texto.py` de esta manera:

```
open(Path(__file__).parent / "archivo_texto.txt")
```

En esa línea de código `Path(__file__)` es la ruta completa al archivo de Python que se está ejecutando.
Para acceder a la carpeta que lo contiene usamos la propiedad [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent).
`Path(__file__).parent` en tu caso será la ruta completa a la carpeta `lectura_carchivos`.
Por último añadimos el nombre del archivo que quieres añadir.
Para ello usamos el operador `/` que, al usarlo con objetos `Path` servirá para concatenar elementos de la ruta.